# How to delete undeletable songs from an iOS device

Tags: ios, music

I have songs on my iPhone 4S that I never intentionally downloaded and can't seem to delete. I have tried to delete them through iTunes but I just cannot seem to get rid of them.

Swiping left on the undeletable song will not show any option to delete the song (oddly enough, swiping left on *other* songs allows me to delete them).

Going into Settings > Usage > Manage Storage allows me to delete all of the songs on my iPhone *except* the undeletable song.

---

(I'm reposting https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6554655 here for greater visibility. I have long searched for an answer for this issue and only now have found an answer that works.)

---

This is not a duplicate question, because in this scenario, iTunes Match has never been activated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Go into Settings > Music > and enable "Show All Music".
2. The undeletable song have the cloud symbol next to them.
3. Redownload the songs.
4. Once finished downloading, go back to settings>music> and disable "show all music" then the swipe-to-delete will work again for the rogue songs. If you don't disable "show all music" it will delete then pop up again.

My theory is that initially when playing songs from the cloud, it caches the song somehow, and when you switch off "Show all music", the cached song remains, but iTunes doesn't see it as an actual song and won't allow deletion.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem on my 4s and came up with this:

First, go to Settings > Music > and enable "Show Apple Music".

Second, start the song playing and then click on the 3 small horizontal lines displayed to the right of the song. "Delete This Song" magically appears. Then just delete, confirm and it's gone!!

Finally, go back into Settings > Music > and disable "Show Apple Music".